# POP3 example from docs.python.org throws error

Tags: python, email, runtime-error

So I am somewhat new to Python and was trying to create a script to download emails from my pop3 server. I found a (seemingly) simple example on Python.org but when I ran the code with my mail server settings I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                           
  File "getmail.py", line 4, in <module>                     
    M.pass_(getpass.getpass())                               
  File "E:\Python32\lib\poplib.py", line 192, in pass_       
    return self._shortcmd('PASS %s' % pswd)                  
  File "E:\Python32\lib\poplib.py", line 155, in _shortcmd   
    return self._getresp()                                   
  File "E:\Python32\lib\poplib.py", line 131, in _getresp    
    raise error_proto(resp)                                  
poplib.error_proto: b'-ERR Authentication failed.'
```

Example code from python.org:

```
import getpass, poplib

M = poplib.POP3('localhost')
M.user(getpass.getuser())
M.pass_(getpass.getpass())
numMessages = len(M.list()[1])
for i in range(numMessages):
    for j in M.retr(i+1)[1]:
        print j
```

The "print j" line throws an error of course. Curiously, the script also fails to ask for the username, only asking for a password which is where the "Authentication failed." comes from I am guessing.

I made the following changes for my script to remove the possibility I keyed in the user/password incorrectly:

```
import getpass, poplib

M = poplib.POP3('mail.myPOP3server.com')
M.user = 'my_username'
M.pass_ = 'myPassword'
numMessages = len(M.list()[1])
for i in range(numMessages):
    for j in M.retr(i+1)[1]:
        print(j)
```

And got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\wos\getmail.py", line 6, in <module>
    numMessages = len(M.list()[1])
  File "E:\Python32\lib\poplib.py", line 219, in list
    return self._longcmd('LIST')
  File "E:\Python32\lib\poplib.py", line 162, in _longcmd
    return self._getlongresp()
  File "E:\Python32\lib\poplib.py", line 138, in _getlongresp
    resp = self._getresp()
  File "E:\Python32\lib\poplib.py", line 131, in _getresp
    raise error_proto(resp)
poplib.error_proto: b'-ERR Unknown command.'
[Finished in 0.4s with exit code 1]
```

So I am convinced that this is where the issue is:

```
numMessages = len(M.list()[1])
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?

I use the docs.python.org regularly for example code and this is the first time I have had example code fail. I tried changing the password to something really short and simple, adding "@servername" to the username and still cannot get a list of emails.

Example code is on this [page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/poplib.html?highlight=retr#poplib.POP3.retr)

UPDATE: I would appreciate if the downvotes were at least explained so I can learn from the process.

Comment: Did you use *your* POP3 server with proper credentials?

Comment: [`getpass.getuser()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html#getpass.getuser) is not supposed to ask for a username, it just gets the name of the current user, so if you need to authenticate with different credentials, replace it with `rawinput`.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Yes I did. And 2 downvotes for this question? Am I in the wrong place or something?

Comment: @mata I would think changing the script to make both username and password a variable would have eliminated this as an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/poplib.html#poplib.POP3.user), `POP3.user` and `POP3.pass_` are *methods* to which you're supposed to pass the username & password, not variables to which the username & password are to be assigned.  Thus, you need to change this:

```
M.user = 'my_username'
M.pass_ = 'myPassword'
```

to this:

```
M.user('my_username')
M.pass_('myPassword')
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this question. Looks like I need to do some more reading and learning. This made all the difference. Works as advertised now. :D